# unable to search with catalog in hybris backoffice

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to search catalogVersion in advanced search Backoffice. when I Type 2-3 letters of catalog code, search is not working, returning empty results.

PFB.
[image]

[image]

But when I type version , results are coming up.

Answer (score 1):

This search can only search on fields directly on the object you search. You cannot search on fields of a sub-object. In this case, you want to search on the `catalog.name` but that's available through `CatalogVersion.Catalog.name`, so one level to deep to search.

While Staged is directly available on `CatalogVersion.version`, so you can search on that.

With the out of the box, you could click on the ... and in that field search for your specific catalog. Then it will be selected in this search box

Comment: can we customize this?

Comment: Yoni, Can u help me in customizing this feature

Comment: I have not done this myself, but I assume you need to find the code that is called when data is entered. that bean you should override to also search in deeper levels. Do be aware that it might have an impact on your performance